# Hangman game in Haskell, written using a state monad

Tags: haskell, hangman, monads

I recently made a simple hangman game in Haskell but soon wanted to explore the state monad, since it could possibly simplify the code. The result was this (see below), which is exactly 30% more lines than not using the monad. My question is therefore: am I using the feature correctly?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# HLINT ignore "Eta reduce" #-}
{-# HLINT ignore "Use fmap" #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-unrecognised-pragmas #-}

import Control.Monad (replicateM_, (>>))
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Functor
import Data.List (elemIndices, sort)
import System.IO (BufferMode (NoBuffering), hFlush, hSetBuffering, stdin)

pictures :: Int
pictures = 9

data Phase = Continue | Win | Loss

instance Show Phase where
  show Loss = "You lost!"
  show Win = "You won!"
  show _ = "Keep going!"

data GameVars = GameVars
  { word :: String,
    rights :: [Char],
    wrongs :: [Char],
    lives :: Int
  }

instance Show GameVars where
  show g@GameVars {word, rights, wrongs, lives} = unlines [renderHangman g, renderLives g, renderWrongs g, renderWord g]

type GameState a = StateT GameVars IO a

main :: IO ()
main = do
  w <- getWord
  clearScreen
  void $ execStateT hang (GameVars {word = w, rights = [], wrongs = [], lives = pictures})

hang :: GameState ()
hang = do
  st <- get
  lift $ print st
  next >>= \case
    Win -> announce Win
    Loss -> announce Loss
    Continue -> again

isLoss :: GameState Bool
isLoss = gets ((== 0) . lives)

announce :: Phase -> GameState ()
announce p = do
  s <- get
  let hangman = renderHangman s
  lift clearScreen
  lift $ putStrLn hangman
  lift $ print p
  lift $ putStrLn ("The correct word was " ++ word s ++ "\n")

again :: GameState ()
again = do
  guess <- lift getGuess
  isCorrect <- correctGuess guess
  lift clearScreen
  st <- get
  let st'
        | guess `elem` (rights st ++ wrongs st) = st
        | isCorrect = st {rights = guess : rights st}
        | otherwise = st {wrongs = guess : wrongs st, lives = lives st - 1}
  put st'
  hang

next :: GameState Phase
next = do
  w <- isWin
  l <- isLoss
  let n
        | w = Win
        | l = Loss
        | otherwise = Continue
  return n

isWin :: GameState Bool
isWin = get >>= \s -> return $ all (`elem` rights s) (word s)

win :: GameState ()
win = do
  s <- get
  put $ s {rights = word s}

clearScreen :: IO ()
clearScreen = replicateM_ 40 (putStrLn "")

correctGuess :: Char -> GameState Bool
correctGuess guess = get <&> ((guess `elem`) . word)

getGuess :: IO Char
getGuess = putStrLn "Guess a letter!" >> getChar

getWord :: IO String
getWord = clearScreen >> putStrLn "Give a secret word!" >> getLine

renderWord :: GameVars -> String
renderWord GameVars {word, rights} = map (\c -> if c `elem` rights then c else '_') word

renderWrongs :: GameVars -> String
renderWrongs GameVars {wrongs = []} = ""
renderWrongs GameVars {wrongs} = "Wrong guesses: " ++ sort wrongs

renderHangman :: GameVars -> String
renderHangman GameVars {lives} = unlines . hangmanpics $ lives

renderLives :: GameVars -> String
renderLives GameVars {lives} = show lives ++ " guesses left!"

hangmanpics :: Int -> [String]
hangmanpics 9 = ["       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "========="]
hangmanpics 8 = ["       ", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 7 = ["  +---+", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 6 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 5 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "  O   |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 4 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "  O   |", "  |   |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 3 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "  O   |", " /|   |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 2 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "  O   |", " /|\\  |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 1 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "  O   |", " /|\\  |", " /    |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 0 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "  O   |", " /|\\  |", " / \\  |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics _ = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "  O   |", " /|\\  |", " / \\  |", "      |", "========="]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is pretty casual, sorry it's not better organized or cited.

- You're not using the bound attribute values in `instance Show GameVars`.
- Instead of `void $ execStateT ...`, just use `evalStateT`.
- Your implementation of `clearScreen` is not really good UX design, but building *good* shell UX is outside the scope of a hangman game :)
- Using `>>=` explicitly is often less readable than just using `do`. In `hang` it makes sense; in `isWin` a `do` would be better.
- An instance of `GameVars` is the state of a game; that's ok. But an instance of `GameState _` is *not* the state of a game; it's not even primarily a functor of such; it's a description of arbitrary behavior in the IO monad involving game state. I suggest renaming these.
- You've broken out a lot of little functions into the top level namespace. This feels like clutter. If a thing fit's inline, put it inline until there's a reason to move it (it gets big enough or you want to share it across locations). The first place to move it is usually a `where` clause, so it's still clear what it's for when someone finds it. As an example, if we inline `isWin` and `isLoss`, the whole logic of `next` becomes *clearer*. (You don't have to like the way I got rid on `n`.) (yes, you will sometimes want to put something in the top namespace just to help you debug it, that's fine.)
- you can often avoid using `lift` so much by leveraging the `MonadIO` class.
- single-character variable names are ok when they are in some sense "fully general", it's kinda a haskell idiom to use them for stuff that's arbitrary *vis a vis* the function. When there's a reasonable word-sized name for a variable, use it.
- With the current logic, you could leave `lives` out of the record, and just have `lives gs = length (rights gs) + length (wrongs gs)`, but it'd make the whole thing more fragile than it needs to be.
- `win` is unused.
- Using a `Show` instance to UI stuff is a normal mistake people make; `Show` is better reserved for debugging purposes, where the resulting string looks basically like the code that created the instance. For UI purposes it's better to have a dedicated function.
- Finding a good abstraction and learning to use it is *hard*. I'm not super fond of monad transformers, but they're an appropriate choice for the task at hand. In this context, prefer `gets` over `get` and `modify` over `put`.
- `hangmanpics` is going to be ugly no matter what you do, don't fight it.
- Is the user supposed to have 9 lives, or 10? I may have an off-by-one mistake in my version.

I need to go do actual work now, so let me know if anything in this version doesn't make sense. We should *not* assume it's "better".

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# HLINT ignore "Eta reduce" #-}
{-# HLINT ignore "Use fmap" #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-unrecognised-pragmas #-}

module CR277633
( main
, hang
) where

import Control.Monad (replicateM_, (>>))
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Functor
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (nub, sort)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import System.IO (BufferMode (NoBuffering), hFlush, hSetBuffering, stdin)

data Phase = Continue | Win | Loss

data GameState = GameState
   { word :: String,
     rights :: [Char],
     wrongs :: [Char],
     lives :: Int
   }

type Gameplay a = StateT GameState IO a

printString :: (MonadIO m) => String -> m ()
printString = liftIO . putStrLn

main :: IO ()
main = do
  clearScreen
  printString "Give a secret word!"
  secretWord <- liftIO getLine
  clearScreen
  evalStateT hang (GameState {word = secretWord,
                              rights = [],
                              wrongs = [],
                              lives = length hangmanpics})

hang :: Gameplay ()
hang = do
  gamestate <- get
  printString $ render gamestate
  result <- next
  handleNext result
  where render GameState{word, rights, wrongs, lives} = unlines [ renderHangman lives
                                                                , show lives ++ " guesses left!"
                                                                , case wrongs of
                                                                    [] -> ""
                                                                    _  -> "Wrong guesses: " ++ sort wrongs
                                                                ,  mask rights <$> word
                                                                ]
        mask known secret = if secret `elem` known then secret else '_'

        next :: Gameplay Phase
        next = do
          gamestate <- get
          let won = all (`elem` rights gamestate) (word gamestate)
              lost = 0 == lives gamestate
          return $ case () of
            _ | won  -> Win
            _ | lost -> Loss
            _        -> Continue

        handleNext :: Phase -> Gameplay ()
        handleNext Continue = do
          printString "Guess a letter!"
          guess <- liftIO getChar
          clearScreen
          rights' <- gets $ nub . (guess :) . rights
          wrongs' <- gets $ nub . (guess :) . wrongs
          lives' <- gets $ newLives guess
          modify (\s -> s {rights = rights', wrongs = wrongs', lives = lives'})
          hang
        handleNext winLose = do
          gamestate <- get
          clearScreen
          (printString . renderHangman) =<< gets lives
          printString $ announcementFor winLose
          (printString . ("The correct word was " ++)) =<< gets word
          printString ""

        announcementFor Loss = "You lost!"
        announcementFor Win = "You won!"
        announcementFor Continue = "Keep going!"  -- unused

        newLives guess GameState{word, rights, wrongs, lives}
          | guess `elem` rights = lives
          | guess `elem` wrongs = lives
          | guess `elem` word   = lives
          | otherwise           = lives - 1

clearScreen :: (MonadIO m) => m ()
clearScreen = replicateM_ 40 (printString "")

renderHangman :: Int -> String
renderHangman lives = if len <= lives then last pics else pics !! lives
  where len = length hangmanpics
        pics = reverse hangmanpics

hangmanpics :: [String]
hangmanpics = ["         \n\
               \         \n\
               \         \n\
               \         \n\
               \         \n\
               \         \n\
               \========="
              ,"         \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \  O   |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \  O   |  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \  O   |  \n\
               \ /|   |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \  O   |  \n\
               \ /|\\  |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \  O   |  \n\
               \ /|\\  |  \n\
               \ /    |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ,"  +---+  \n\
               \  |   |  \n\
               \  O   |  \n\
               \ /|\\  |  \n\
               \ / \\  |  \n\
               \      |  \n\
               \========="
              ]
```

Comment: These were some really hands-on great tips for writing idiomatic Haskell code. Many, many thanks! Especially about creating Show instances, that caught me off guard but makes total sense. I was also conceptually wrong about "GameState", thanks for catching that, too. I'll make sure to go over each bullet thoroughly!